# log4net DLL gets corrupted (set to all zeroes)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, log4net, corruption

We've recently started seeing an issue where log4net.dll is corrupted - specifically, it is the right size but contains all zeroes.  This causes BadImageFormatExceptions (ultimately wrapped in TypeInitializationExceptions since we tend to initialize our ILog instances statically in each class).  This happens sporadically and without a discernible pattern.  Uninstalling and reinstalling our app seems to "fix" it, in that we haven't (yet) seen the issue twice on the same machine - but that could just be coincidence.

Our application consists of a Windows service and a "regular" Windows app which communicate via named pipes (nothing too unusual).  We've used log4net in the regular app for a long time (before I joined the project), but only recently added log4net to the service.  We initialize it using the same mechanism in both applications, specifically:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And we typically instantiate ILog instances statically in each class, i.e.:

```
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (SomeClass));
```

So far, we have considered the following but without any hard evidence to lead us to a conclusion:

1. An installer issue.  We're using a pretty standard MSI installer, and this file is simply copied normally as part of the install.  It's not the first or last file copied.  Furthermore, we've seen at least one instance where the issue didn't manifest until a day or so after the install (whereas most of the occurrences have happened shortly or immediately after install).  We have, however, recently cleaned up the installer so there have been changes there (unfortunately I can't speak to them in great detail, as the installer work was done by someone else and MSI is not something I'm deeply familiar with).
2. Interaction with anti-virus software.  All the machines that we've seen the issue on (4-5) have the same AV software (Sophos), but there's no indication in any Sophos logs of log4net getting flagged or quarantined.
3. Something related to using log4net in the Windows service application.

As you can see, we have reasons to doubt #1 and #2, but haven't yet ruled anything out, and have very little evidence for or against #3.  Since this is our first release where we're using log4net in the service, it obviously seems suspicious that we're now seeing the DLL get corrupted - but we also had our dev, QA, and beta testers using early iterations of this release for several weeks before this started occurring, so there isn't an obvious correlation with respect to the timing of the change.

We've also tried automating the uninstall/reinstall process to run repeatedly to see if we could shake anything out (nothing after several thousand installs).  We've got all users in our office running with ProcMon so that if we see it again, we can hopefully see what touches the file, but that means at this point we're in a waiting game.

Any thoughts on how we could more definitively rule some of our possible causes in or out, or any info from someone who's seen this issue specifically would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
We haven't seen this as much recently, though that's probably due at least in part to lower usage of the installer.  However, one key change that we made recently was turning off publisher evidence for the service application (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

We made this change (as the above link recommends for service applications) to improve our startup times since we were occasionally seeing the service time out and fail to start.  However, we also haven't seen the log4net.dll corruption issue since we made this change.  Is it possible that by disabling this feature, we are bypassing some sort of operation that could potentially mangle the log4net.dll (which is a strongly-named assembly)?  We don't want to assume we've fixed the issue just because we haven't seen it in a few weeks, since we don't have any hard evidence and thus it could just be coincidence

Again, any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: one thing you could try: install the DLL into GAC and see whether it gets corrupted...

Comment: @Yahia: thanks for the suggestion, we may go that route eventually.  The only problem is that it happens so randomly that we don't have a definitive test for whether it's fixed - we basically just have to wait and see if it stops happening.  Still hoping someone can shed some light on what's happening...

Comment: Our product is also a windows service w/ named pipes etc.  We have also very rarely seen this issue (twice, each time a few random machines out of many of the same image at a site).  In each case we actually had logs written from the dll for a short time before something zeroed the dll, so it's not the install/update process.   It's not a problem with log4net itself either because some of our other dlls were zeroed.  Leaning toward anti-virus, one of the instances did have Sophos, the other had McAffee